# How can i find a current apk version whie using appium?

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android

I want to find a current apk version while executing my automation script.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it via adb: `dumpsys package <your app package> | grep version`

And here you can find [example](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/) how to run adb command via appium